# Connect to Active Directory using Java JNDI

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I am new to using JNDI and I am trying to connect to Active Directory using JNDI and I am facing either Authentication Error or Connection Time out. I am unable to understand what is the potential reason.This how my Active Directory looks like

[image]

I have tried the following code

```
public class ConnectAD {

static DirContext ldapContext;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    try {
        System.out.println("Début du test Active Directory");

        Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://172.16.1.179:389");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ou=Users,ou=Test1,dc=gigabyte,dc=local");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "5uperCharger");          

         ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
        //LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(ldapEnv,null);
```

I get the error at while creating the InitialDirContext.

I have an administrator user but I tried giving the cn=administrator but could not connect. I was getting an Authentication Error when I do so.

I also have a name to my ADServer which is GIGA(just trying to provide as much as i can)
Can you please let me know what can be the issue.

Comment: The security principal should be the full DN of a user, not just the base DN. Have you tried adding CN=Jared?

Comment: Yes giving the full DN worked. Thank you.